# Assigning Automatic Formatting to Specific Extensions in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to have my .erb and .scss files open in Notepad++ with the formatting normally applied to .html and .css files, respectively. Normally this is simple - go to Settings -> Style Configurator -> Language: HTML (or CSS) and add "erb" to the "User ext." section. This works perfectly.

However, when I follow those exact same steps after having changed the "Select theme:" menu at the top of the Style Configurator window from Default to "Deep Black" (my preferred theme), the custom extensions refuse to save. Any ideas why, and what will fix it? Thanks.

I'm using Notepad++ v6.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Still not sure why it won't save via the Style Configurator, but you can make the change manually:

Access the Notepad++ folder in your Program Files directory.  Locate the "Deep Black.xml" file within the "themes" folder and open it (I needed to move this file out of that folder before making any changes to it).  Locate the line that begins the HTML section, which is:

```
<LexerType name="html" desc="HTML" ext="">
```

Add 'erb' to the 'ext' attribute.  Save the file and add it back to the themes folder (you may want to change the original Deep Black file to a '.bak', so you can have it as a backup instead of overwriting it).  Repeat for any other file types (such as .scss).